# How to avoid temporary allocations when using a complex key for a HashMap?

Tags: rust

I'm using a complex key for `HashMap` such that the key comprises two parts and one part is a `String`, and I can't figure out how to do lookups via the `HashMap::get` method without allocating a new `String` for each lookup.

Here's some code:

```
#[derive(Debug, Eq, Hash, PartialEq)]
struct Complex {
    n: i32,
    s: String,
}

impl Complex {
    fn new<S: Into<String>>(n: i32, s: S) -> Self {
        Complex { n: n, s: s.into() }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut m = std::collections::HashMap::<Complex, i32>::new();
    m.insert(Complex::new(42, "foo"), 123);

    // OK, but allocates temporary String
    assert_eq!(123, *m.get(&Complex::new(42, "foo")).unwrap());
}
```

The problem is with the final assertion. It passes, but it requires a temporary heap allocation because I cannot construct a `Complex` without constructing a `String`.

To eliminate temporary allocations like this, Rust provides the [`Borrow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html) trait, which the `HashMap::get` method makes use of. I understand how to make `Borrow` work for simple keys. For example, the Rust Standard Library's `PathBuf` implements `Borrow<Path>` by making use of `std::mem::transmute` under the hood, but I can't figure out how to make it work for my `Complex` type:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Borrowable {
    // ??? -- What goes here? Perhaps something like:
    n: i32,
    s1: &str, // ??? -- But what would the lifetime be? Or maybe:
    s2: str,  // ??? -- But how would I extend this to a complex type
              //        containing two or more strings?
}

impl Borrowable {
    fn new(n: i32, s: &str) -> &Self {
         // ??? -- What goes here? It must not allocate.
        unimplemented!();
    }
}

impl std::borrow::Borrow<Borrowable> for Complex {
    fn borrow(&self) -> &Borrowable {
        // ??? -- What goes here? How can I transmute a Complex into a
        //        &Borrowable?
        unimplemented!();
    }
}
```

This seems like a common use case, and I suspect I'm missing something important about `Borrow`, but I'm at a total loss.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like you want this.

`Cow` will accept a `&str` or `String`.

```
use std::borrow::Cow;

#[derive(Debug, Eq, Hash, PartialEq)]
struct Complex<'a> {
    n: i32,
    s: Cow<'a, str>,
}

impl<'a> Complex<'a> {
    fn new<S: Into<Cow<'a, str>>>(n: i32, s: S) -> Self {
        Complex { n: n, s: s.into() }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut m = std::collections::HashMap::<Complex<'_>, i32>::new();
    m.insert(Complex::new(42, "foo"), 123);

    assert_eq!(123, *m.get(&Complex::new(42, "foo")).unwrap());
}
```

A comment about lifetime parameters:

If you don't like the lifetime parameter and you only need to work with `&'static str` or `String` then you can use `Cow<'static, str>` and remove the other lifetime parameters from the impl block and struct definition.

Comment: I'm gonna need a day or two to digest this. It's simple, yet it blows my mind. My main concern is that in my particular case `Complex` is exposed in my crate's API, so I need to make sure I can burden the type with a lifetime parameter without muddying my interface too much. My initial reaction is that `Cow`'s copy-on-write functionality is too heavy because I'm never doing any copying, but in a sense I almost am, because sometimes I'm using instances and sometimes I'm using references. After I finish digesting your answer, I'll let you know how it works.

Comment: You might be able to get rid of the lifetime parameters. See my edit.

Comment: I cannot eliminate the lifetime parameter because I sometimes borrow from a non-static `str`. Nonetheless, I really like your idea because it would simplify code elsewhere because the new `Complex` covers both the owning and borrowing cases—no need for a unique type for each case. One thing that intrigues me is that the Rust Standard Library didn't go the route of using `Cow` in instead of having two types to cover the owning and borrowing cases for `Path`/`PathBuf` et al. The `Cow` idea seems more generalized because it works for complex types, too. Was this done for run-time efficiency?

Answer (score 8):

You can follow the ideas described in [How to implement HashMap with two keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45786717/155423). Here's the ["borrowed trait object" answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45795699/155423) applied to your case:

Create a trait that we can use as a common `Borrow` target:

```
trait Key {
    fn to_key(&self) -> (i32, &str);
}
```

Implement the `HashMap`-required traits for the trait object:

```
use std::hash::{Hash, Hasher};

impl Hash for dyn Key + '_ {
    fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, state: &mut H) {
        self.to_key().hash(state)
    }
}

impl PartialEq for dyn Key + '_ {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.to_key() == other.to_key()
    }
}

impl Eq for dyn Key + '_ {}
```

Implement the trait for our primary type and any secondary lookup types:

```
impl Key for Complex {
    fn to_key(&self) -> (i32, &str) {
        (self.n, &self.s)
    }
}

impl<'a> Key for (i32, &'a str) {
    fn to_key(&self) -> (i32, &str) {
        (self.0, self.1)
    }
}
```

Implement `Borrow` for all the lookup types as returning our trait object:

```
impl<'a> Borrow<dyn Key + 'a> for Complex {
    fn borrow(&self) -> &(dyn Key + 'a) {
        self
    }
}

impl<'a> Borrow<dyn Key + 'a> for (i32, &'a str) {
    fn borrow(&self) -> &(dyn Key + 'a) {
        self
    }
}
```

Convert to the trait object at query time:

```
assert_eq!(Some(&123), m.get((42, "foo").borrow() as &dyn Key));
```

[The complete code in the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f2073bd67e04c8e21a875e4183a2c79c)

---

One important "gotcha" is that all of your primary key and your secondary keys **must** hash in the same manner. This means that the same values need to go into the hash computation in the same order and amount.

You may wish to define `Hash` by hand to ensure that your primary and secondary keys hash the same!

Here's another example, this time with an enum:

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
enum ConfigKey {
    Text(String),
    Binary(Vec<u8>),
}
```

We create a parallel enum that is composed of only references, so it's lightweight to create. It's important that we define the same variants and in the same order as the primary enum so they will hash the same. We rely on the fact that `String` and `&str` hash using the same algorithm, as do `Vec<T>` and `&[T]`:

```
impl ConfigKey {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> ConfigKeyRef<'_> {
        match self {
            ConfigKey::Text(t) => ConfigKeyRef::Text(t),
            ConfigKey::Binary(b) => ConfigKeyRef::Binary(b),
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Hash, PartialEq, Eq)]
enum ConfigKeyRef<'a> {
    Text(&'a str),
    Binary(&'a [u8]),
}
```

We use this new enum as our common underlying key type:

```
trait Key {
    fn to_key(&self) -> ConfigKeyRef<'_>;
}
```

And implement our trait for our primary and secondary keys:

```
impl Key for ConfigKey {
    fn to_key(&self) -> ConfigKeyRef<'_> {
        self.as_ref()
    }
}

impl<'a> Key for &'a str {
    fn to_key(&self) -> ConfigKeyRef<'_> {
        ConfigKeyRef::Text(self)
    }
}
```

[The complete code in the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e17fe5054ad3124ff3c0c70749983bc0)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`hashbrown`](https://docs.rs/hashbrown) crate directly (it is the underlying implementation of std's `HashMap`). Instead of `Borrow`, it provides a more flexible [`Equivalent`](https://docs.rs/hashbrown/latest/hashbrown/trait.Equivalent.html) trait, that you can use in your example:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Hash)]
struct BorrowedComplex<'a> {
    n: i32,
    s: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> BorrowedComplex<'a> {
    fn new(n: i32, s: &'a str) -> Self {
        Self { n, s }
    }
}

impl hashbrown::Equivalent<Complex> for BorrowedComplex<'_> {
    fn equivalent(&self, key: &Complex) -> bool {
        self.n == key.n && self.s == key.s
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut m = hashbrown::HashMap::<Complex, i32>::new();
    m.insert(Complex::new(42, "foo"), 123);

    assert_eq!(123, *m.get(&BorrowedComplex::new(42, "foo")).unwrap());
}
```