# Look up key in HashMap<(String, usize), f64> in Rust

Tags: rust

I have a `HashMap<(String, usize), f64>`. I also have a `&str` and a `usize`, which I would like to look up in this `HashMap` without cloning. Is there a way to lookup a `(&str, usize)` as a `(String, usize)` somehow?

Comment: If possible, you must use `Cow`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36480845/how-to-avoid-temporary-allocations-when-using-complex-key-for-hashmap

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use `HashMap<(&str, usize), f64>`? It could be that I don't understand rust well enough but that seems like a reasonable solution to me.

Comment: @user25064 something needs to hold the allocation of the `String`, and perhaps the key of the map is the most natural. Splitting the two up is a potential solution though, depending on the usecase.

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't.  The options for looking up in the `HashMap<K,V>` are:

- The `entry` method, which requires a `K` by value, which in your case is a `(String, usize)` - so you'd need to construct a `String`.
- The various `get`, `contains_key` etc. all take a "borrowed" form of `K` (the documentation says `&Q`, where `K: Borrow<Q>`; this means either a `&(String, usize)` or something that can produced one.

Technically you could iterate through it and do your own comparisons, but that's probably not what you want!

Comment: Note that this is no longer true. With edition 2018, you can look up String keys with &str.

Answer (score 4):

There is, however, a method to do this that does not involve allocating a string. But you'll have to change your Hashmap so the key is of type `(std::borrow::Cow<'a, str>, usize)` (for some lifetime `'a`). Then you can look up values with `map.get((Cow::Borrowed(my_str_slice), 0))`.