# How can I implement Borrow for an enum variant so that I can use a string slice as a key for a HashMap?

Tags: rust, borrowing

In the following scenario:

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
struct Key(String);

fn get_from_map(map: HashMap<Key, i32>, key: &str) {
    // ???
}
```

I can implement this by using the `Borrow` trait, so I don't need a `&Key`, just a `&str` is fine:

```
impl Borrow<str> for Key {
    fn borrow(&self) -> &str {
        &self.0
    }
}

fn get_from_map(map: HashMap<Key, i32>, key: &str) {
    map.get(key);
}
```

However, when my key is an enum, there's no way to implement `Borrow`:

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
enum Key {
    Text(String),
    Binary(Vec<u8>)
}

fn get_from_map(map: HashMap<Key, i32>, key: &str) {
    // ???
}
```

Is there an ergonomic way to implement `get_from_map`, without cloning `key`, so that it somehow only looks for `Text` keys?

My first instinct is implement `Borrow` for a `BorrowedKey` newtype but that doesn't seem to work since `Borrow` needs to return a reference.

Comment: Something like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ef79aaf7926aa03b5127d26302efbe7a&version=stable&mode=debug)?

Comment: You need the same implementation to  work for both types of key?

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [How to implement HashMap with two keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45786717/155423). See also the answer to [How to avoid temporary allocations when using complex key for HashMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50478038/155423) which is the same logic. If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: The [duplicate applied to your situation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3eb216ccefb1533fea1a0e1dff5627f8&version=stable&mode=debug).

Comment: @PeterHall Sorry I wasn't specific enough. My intent was not to clone the string.